# How to perform extrinsic rotations

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations

I have a point $(1,2,0)$ and I want to rotate it around the global $x$ axis by $45^{\circ}$, and around the global $y$ axis by $60^{\circ}$ and $0^{\circ}$ around the global $z$ axis.

How exactly can I do this?

Please show all of the exact matrices used in the multiplication and how they are formed. I am only a new a level student and have only really learnt about the basic $3d$ rotation matrices, and I need this for a Rubik's cube game.

An example of this can be found on the following [website/article](https://dominicplein.medium.com/extrinsic-intrinsic-rotation-do-i-multiply-from-right-or-left-357c38c1abfd):

What I need: second plane animation

What I don't want: first plane animation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Rubik's cube is never rotated by 45 or 60 degrees. Downvote.

Comment: wth bro, i mean the FULL rubiks cube. im pretty sure you can turn the full rubiks cube by 45 degrees, or can i?????

Comment: Sure but this has nothing specifically to do with the Rubiks cube. You can do that with any rigid body. It is puzzling that you learned about basic 3d rotation matrices and want us to do that work for you. What exactly have you learned ? Please write down for me the 3d rotation matrix that rotates the cube by 45 degrees around the $x$ axis.

Comment: i have been researching everywhere to find the ways to do this for MONTHS, and i can find no information on how to do this, apart from some crap about having do 'mulitply the other way'

Comment: rotation matrices can be found on wikipedia in the 3d rotation matrices section, uner basic 3d rotation matrices.      i cant even find a video on youtube about this.

Comment: Since you found the rotation matrices on Wikipedia, those are the exact formulas for rotation around each axis, just plug in the desired rotation angle. (Since it appears you're doing this in software, make sure you use the units that your software functions expect for angles -- sin(angle) and cos(angle) usually expect radians.) It's not clear what else we can tell you. Do you need us to tell you what the sines and cosines of $0$ degrees, $45$ degrees, and $60$ degrees are?

Comment: Multiply (in reverse order of speech) these two matrices $\pmatrix{s&0&-c\\0&1&0\\c&0&s}\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&a&-a\\0&a&a}$ where $a:=\sqrt{2}/2$, $c=1/2$, $s=\sqrt{3}/2$ and apply it to whatever vector you like... Besides, what do you think a rotation of $0°$ is ?!?

Comment: If you're looking for an **animation**, it's not enough to just write three matrices, one for each axis. The three matrices you asked for only produce the final orientation, which is the same in both examples. In order to animate the motion, you need your software to generate a sequence of frames in which you have less rotation than in the final position.

Comment: oh,ok. Thanks a lot!